# How do I set up a split tunnel on the server side using OpenVPN?

Tags: openvpn, split-tunnel

I want my OpenVPN client to route all 134.94/16 traffic through the non-VPN default gateway, and the rest through the VPN. In my incompetence, I added the following line to my server-side openvpn.conf:

```
push "route 134.94.0.0 255.255.0.0 134.94.xxx.xxx"
```

This seems to be ignored, though.  Besides, I don’t want the gateway address to be static since my working place admin may change it.  So, how can I make my clients to use their old non-VPN gateway for some IP address range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the special gateway `net_gateway`, which the client-side OpenVPN will translate to whatever it recognizes as the original default gateway address.

```
push "route 134.94.0.0 255.255.0.0 net_gateway"
```

Of course, for push to work, the client actually needs to `pull` configuration from server, instead of trying to do its own route settings. (If it does, then the whole `route ...` option can be placed on the client as well.)

Note that "more specific" (longer netmask) routes always take priority over shorter ones, so if your VPN server happens to push – for example – a /24 route (255.255.255.0), it will be taken as higher priority than your /16 (255.255.0.0).

Comment: I mark this as answered because AFAICS it is correct. However, it still does not work for me, probably because of https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager-openvpn/+bug/1603600.

Comment: Ah, I think NM specifically ignores (or rather _lacks support for_) the pushed "net_gateway" routes...